# Set the value of a primary workflow's associated list field using Secondary Task workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a primary list and workflow. i create a To-Do task from the primary workflow called "Setup Project Artifact Requirements".

Creating of this task triggers a secondary workflow on the task list called "RACI Status Field Update" that i was HOPING to use to monitor the Task, and when the Task was "Completed" set the value of a field in the primary workflow's associated list called "Project Initiation".

[image: secondary Task List Workflow]

is this not possible?? in the workflow actions for the secondary workflow i do NOT see the "set any value" action.

[image: Actions available for secondary workflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use Update List Item, this will allow you to specify what list you want to look up and update.